# applicationWillTerminate deadlock

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos, grand-central-dispatch

I want to close all VZVirtualMachine instances when my app is terminating. Im using this code in the `AppDelegate`

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ notification: Notification) {
    let runningEntities = runningEntities
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: -runningEntities.count)
    runningEntities.forEach { entity in
        entity.virtualMachine.stop { _ in
            semaphore.signal()
        }
    }
    semaphore.wait()
}
```

The problem is, that callback in `stop {}` is (I think) dispatched to main thread. So adding `semaphore.wait()` causes the main thread to be blocked, and the callback never gets executed. What would be the solution to this? I need to wait until all machines `stop {}` function is finished, and the only way I know that is by reading this callback.

Comment: Have you tried `applicationShouldTerminate(_:)` with reply `.terminateLater`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Willeke's comment I was able to solve this. The code below:

```
func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {
    let runningEntities = runningEntities
    var counter = runningEntities.count
    func finishIfReady() {
        if counter == 0 {
            sender.reply(toApplicationShouldTerminate: true)
        }
    }
    defer {
        for entity in runningEntities {
            entity.virtualMachine.stop { _ in
                counter -= 1
                finishIfReady()
            }
        }
    }
    return .terminateLater
}
```